# How to fix printing from a networked printer in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, network-printer, ubuntu-15.04

I have a shared printer connected to a machine running Ubuntu server. The printer is shared and does print properly time to time. When I start my laptop running Windows 10 it prints fine, no hassles, but after a couple hours (my laptop doesn't sleep or hibernate) it will send the document to the printer on the Windows machine but not print or display any type of error. When I restart my computer, prints fine. I have tried using CUPS and SMB printer sharing doesn't make a difference. Any suggestions?